# Phonegap Build & Parse.com: Parse.initialize Error ONLY in Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, phonegap-build

I'm using PhoneGap to make a mobile app from a website. I recently switched to Parse.com as a cloud back-end.

- When I test my mobile app using Ripple Emulator/browser, Parse.com calls work fine.
- When I test it using PhoneGap Developer App on my Galaxy S4, Parse.com calls work fine.
- ONLY when I build my app using PhoneGap Build and open on my Galaxy S4 do the Parse.com calls not work. The tables that should be created with Parse.com data do not appear and form submissions to Parse.com do not go through.

I have already implemented some suggestions made here on StackOverflow to no luck: I have set  in my config.xml and added  in my html headers.

I will post my code once I get home later today. Please help; I've been stuck on this bug for the whole weekend already!

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED

Replace the CDN with a local copy of the file. Simple but not intuitive solution. Hope this helped other PhoneGap / Parse.com users